# Vue3: Can't fetch when page reloaded, but can fetch when redirected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I'm having an issue with fetching an object inside of my Vuex store. I think the problem resides in either the `setup()` or `mount()`.

So, whenever I login, I want to be redirected to my profile page (`/login ->/me`). When this happens, I manage to pull the necessary information from the Vuex store:
[image]

So far so good. However, when I reload the page, I can't seem to fetch the data and get these errors in the console:

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:38 [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of render function 
  at <VCardTitle> 
  at <VCard> 
  at <VRow justify="center" > 
  at <ProfilePage onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
...
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:38 [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug. Please open an issue at https://new-issue.vuejs.org/?repo=vuejs/core 
  at <VCardTitle> 
  at <VCard> 
  at <VRow justify="center" > 
  at <ProfilePage onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
...
ProfilePage.vue:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toUpperCase')
    at ProfilePage.vue:6:63
    at Proxy.renderFnWithContext (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:847:21)
    at Proxy.<anonymous> (createSimpleFunctional.ts:22:10)
    at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:890:44)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5602:57)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:185:25)
    at instance.update (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5716:56)
    at setupRenderEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5730:9)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5512:9)
    at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5470:17)
```

I know the vuex store contains the data thru the Vue DevTools.

Here's my code:

```js
//ProfilePage.vue
<template>
  <nav-bar></nav-bar>
  <v-row justify="center">
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title>
        {{ currentUser.first_name }} {{ currentUser.last_name.toUpperCase() }}
      </v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>
        {{ currentUser.description }}
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-row>
</template>
<script>
import { computed } from "vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex";
export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  setup() {
    const store = useStore();
    return {
      currentUser: computed(() => store.getters.getUser),
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show what's happening in your Vuex.

Also you're importing `computed` from `@vue/runtime-core`.

The docs said it's not for app use i.e internal use only.

Docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/runtime-core

Next, assign an empty string instead as default value instead of `undefined` or at least check in the template if `currentUser.last_name`.

You have `{{ currentUser.last_name.toUpperCase() }}` in your template and the error says

> ProfilePage.vue:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toUpperCase')

Here's a working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-73912912-6f6syv